# Setar uma String no yml

Tags: java

Olá, estou criando um sistema de configuração com SnakeYaml para minhas aplicações, gostaria de saber como q eu poderia estar setando um valor para uma seção na .yml

```
    private Map<Object, Object> map;
    private final Yaml yaml = new Yaml();

    private String path;
    private String section;
    private InputStream inputStream;

    @SuppressWarnings({"unused"})
    public void load(String path) throws IOException {
        this.path = path;
        inputStream = Files.newInputStream(new File(path).toPath());
        map = new HashMap<>(yaml.load(inputStream));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.load("resource.yml");
        configuration.set("seção a ser setada", "valor a ser setado");
    }

    public void set(String s, String p)  {
       ## codigo para setar
    }
```

Por exemplo, na config.yml está assim

```
status: 'ATIVADO'
```

E gostaria de pelo set() setar o valor para 'DESLIGADO'

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Vc vai usar o método `yaml.dump` e sobrescrever o conteúdo do arquivo original.

Olha o exemplo:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Map;

import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;

class Main {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    Path path = Path.of(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "config.yml");

    Yaml yaml = new Yaml();

    Map<String, String> result = read(yaml, path);

    if (result.get("status").equals("ATIVADO")) {
      result.put("status", "DESATIVADO");

      write(yaml, path, result);
    }
  }

  private static Map<String, String> read(Yaml yaml, Path path) {
    try (InputStream input = Files.newInputStream(path)) {
      return yaml.load(input);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return Map.of();
    }
  }

  private static void write(Yaml yaml, Path path, Map<String, String> content) {
    try (Writer output = Files.newBufferedWriter(path)) {
      yaml.dump(content, output);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```